# Como remover caracteres repetidos de uma string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Essa é minha função:

```
let longest = (s1, s2) => {
      var s1 = `xyaabbbccccdefww`;
      var s2 = `yestheyarehere`;
      let res2 = s1.concat(s2);


      console.log(res2);

    };
```

Comment: Ola @Isa, tem essa postagem no stack overflow americano, talvez te ajude. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19730642/7755215

Comment: Repetidos só na sequencia ou repetidos mesmo que em lugares diferentes da string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Fonte**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50649912/remove-duplicate-character-in-string-and-make-unique-string)

**Com reduce**

```js
var s1 = `xyaabbbccccdefww`;
var s2 = `yestheyarehere`;
   let res2 = s1.concat(s2);

const remDup= s=> s.split("").sort().reduce((a,b)=>(a[a.length-1]!=b)?(a+b):a,"")
console.log(remDup(res2))
```

**Com filter:**

```js
    var s1 = `xyaabbbccccdefww`;
    var s2 = `yestheyarehere`;
       let res2 = s1.concat(s2);

const remDup= s=> s.split("").filter((e,i,f)=>f.indexOf(e)==i).sort().join("")
console.log(remDup(res2))
```

**Com map**

```js
var s1 = `xyaabbbccccdefww`;
var s2 = `yestheyarehere`;
   let res2 = s1.concat(s2);

const remDup= s=> s.split("").map((c,i,o)=>(o.indexOf(c)==i)?c:"").sort().join("")
console.log(remDup(res2))
```

> Você pode usar o novo operador `spread` do JavaScript com `Set` para obter uma matriz de valores exclusivos.
>
> O objeto  [**Set**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) permite que você armazene valores únicos de qualquer tipo

```js
var s1 = `xyaabbbccccdefww`;
var s2 = `yestheyarehere`;
   let res2 = s1.concat(s2);

   const remDup= e => [...new Set(e)].sort().join("");
   console.log(remDup(res2))
```

[**Spread syntax**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

O Spread Operator basicamente converte um array em argumentos, ele é muito útil quando se precisar quebrar um array para passar seus valores para uma função ou construtor de um objeto como argumentos de valores separados. Para exemplificar na prática, vamos criar uma simples função de soma, que precisa de 2 argumentos como parâmetro de entrada em sua função:

```
 function soma(a, b) {
     return a + b;
   }
```

Se você pretende usar essa função você pode simplesmente fazer

```
 soma(1, 2); // retorna: 3
```

E se você pretende usar um array? Como passar 2 valores de um array como argumento? O jeito mais óbvio seria:

```
 var arr = [1, 2];
 soma(arr[0], arr[1]); // retorna: 3
```

Tem um jeito mais elegante? Tem! Você pode usar `soma.apply(null, arr)` para invocar essa função:

```
 var arr = [1, 2];
 soma.apply(null, arr); // retorna: 3
```

Com o Spread operator

```
 var arr = [1, 2];
 soma(...arr); // retorna: 3
```

Comment: Por falar em xurupitas, vou começar a usar essa variável, vai evitar conflitos com certeza rs

Comment: @sam, opa já é >> xurupitas® ou  xurupitas™

Answer (score 3):

Basicamente a regex que você precisa é essa: `replace(/(.)(?=.*\1)/g, "")`

Seu código pode ficar assim:

```
let longest = (s1, s2) => {
  var s1 = `xyaabbbccccdefww`;
  var s2 = `yestheyarehere`;
  let res2 = s1.concat(s2);
  let str =  res2.replace(/(.)(?=.*\1)/g, "");
  console.log(str);
};
```